# MvvmCross initialization

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

In question [Using MvvmCross from content providers and activities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862980/using-mvvmcross-from-content-providers-and-activities) I wanted to know of how to initialize the MvvmCross system.

The answer given worked then, but with recent updates of MvvmCross the function which I used (MvxAndroidSetupSingleton.GetOrCreateSetup()) has been deprecated.

I have now changed my initialization and it seems to work so far, but is it correct and proper? Should I do things differently to improve portability?

Setup class, in platform specific DLL for Android:

```
public class Setup
   : MvxAndroidSetup
{
    public Setup(Context applicationContext)
        : base(applicationContext)
    {
    }

    protected override IMvxApplication CreateApp()
    {
        // Create logger class which can be used from now on
        var logger = new AndroidLogger();
        Mvx.RegisterSingleton(typeof(ILogger), logger);
        var app = new App();
        InitialisePlatformSpecificStuff();
        return app;
    }

    private void InitialisePlatformSpecificStuff()
    {
        // For instance register platform specific classes with IoC
    }
}
```

And my App class in the portable core library:

```
public class App
    : MvxApplication
{
    public App()
    {
    }

    public override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledExceptionHandler;
        InitialisePlugins();
        InitaliseServices();
        InitialiseStartNavigation();
    }

    private void InitaliseServices()
    {
        CreatableTypes().EndingWith("Service").AsInterfaces().RegisterAsLazySingleton();
    }

    private void InitialiseStartNavigation()
    {
    }

    private void InitialisePlugins()
    {
        // initialise any plugins where are required at app startup
        // e.g. Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Visibility.PluginLoader.Instance.EnsureLoaded();
    }

    public static void UnhandledExceptionHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        // Log exception info etc
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

> the function which I used (MvxAndroidSetupSingleton.GetOrCreateSetup()) has been deprecated.

The changes to MvvmCross initialization were required to help users avoid 'multiple splashscreen' issues - see https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/274.

The core of these changes was:

- https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/commit/37f9dc76d3eca1fd2a7379597b73365c772e23a3

So you can see that this change removed the lines:

```
-  var setup = MvxAndroidSetupSingleton.GetOrCreateSetup(activity.ApplicationContext);
-  setup.EnsureInitialized(androidView.GetType());
```

and replaced them with:

```
+  var setupSingleton = MvxAndroidSetupSingleton.EnsureSingletonAvailable(activity.ApplicationContext);
+  setupSingleton.EnsureInitialized();
```

So your changes will need to reflect this same code.

Comment: Ooops. I forgot to include my setup code used in OnCreate... It was exactly as you showed.