# MvvmCross - How to start the application from a Notification

Tags: android, xamarin.android, notifications, mvvmcross, startup

I am using MvvmCross 6.4.3.

If the app is not running, and I click on a notification I have received from the app previously, the app does not go to the first page (in my case the logon page)

When the app is started by the user NavigateToFirstViewModel is called in my custom MvxAppStart, it then calls MvxApplication.Startup.

However when I attempt, to start the app from a notification, none of these are called and so my first page is not displayed.

Where should I put the code to navigate to the first page, so that it is only called in the case of starting from a notification

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it. I've posted this on [Github](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/2418#issuecomment-469793099):

For starters you want to specify the singleTop launch mode for your activity:

```cs
[Activity(LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop, ...)]
public class MainActivity : MvxAppCompatActivity
```

Generate the notification `PendingIntent` like this:

```cs
var intent = new Intent(Context, typeof(MainActivity));
intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
// Putting an extra in the Intent to pass data to the MainActivity
intent.PutExtra("from_notification", true);
var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(Context, notificationId, intent, 0);
```

Now there are places to handle this Intent from `MainActivity` while still allowing the use of MvvmCross navigation service:

1. `OnCreate` - If the app was not running while the notification was clicked then `OnCreate` will be called.

```cs
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    if (bundle == null && Intent.HasExtra("from_notification"))
    {
        // The notification was clicked while the app was not running. 
        // Calling MvxNavigationService multiple times in a row here won't always work as expected. Use a Task.Delay(), Handler.Post(), or even an MvvmCross custom presentation hint to make it work as needed.
        var mvxNavigationService = MvvmCross.Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMvxNavigationService>();
        await mvxNavigationService.Navigate<ViewModel>();
        var handler = new Handler(Looper.MainLooper);
        handler.Post(async () => await mvxNavigationService.Navigate<AnotherViewModel>();
    }
}
```

2. `OnNewIntent` - If the app was running while the notification was clicked then `OnNewIntent` will be called.

```cs
protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    base.OnNewIntent(intent);
    if (intent.HasExtra("from_notification"))
    {
        // The notification was clicked while the app was already running.
        // Back stack is already setup.
        // Show a new fragment using MvxNavigationService.
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct, this is how to detect if the app has been opened with a notification click. The issue is how to start the app from a notification click and not have just a white screen. For me, the key was in my answer `var setupSingleton = MvxAndroidSetupSingleton.EnsureSingletonAvailable(this);
setupSingleton.EnsureInitialized();`, then navigating to my start page. I'm wondering how you did it?

Comment: I've updated my `OnCreate` snippet showing how I'm navigating when opening the app from a notification. Using `Handler.Post` was the only way I found to make it reliably navigate to more than one VM. You could also use a MvvmCross presentation hint instead and do advanced navigation.

Answer (score 0):

I have had to manually do it. Not sure if that is the official way but I also did not find out how anyone else did it.

- App opened with notification click.
- In your Activity `OnCreate` method check for the notification extra in the `Intent`. If it contains the notification then you know it has been started with a notification click.
- Ensure the app has been set up.

```
var setupSingleton = MvxAndroidSetupSingleton.EnsureSingletonAvailable(this);
setupSingleton.EnsureInitialized();
```

- Navigate to desired start page.

Comment: I'm assuming OnCreate is not called in the activity for the case where the application is running own it receives a notification. So there is no specific "hook" or event in the MVVM Cross framework to handle this?

Comment: Correct, OnCreate is not called when the Activity is resumed. There is no hook or event in MvvmCross to handle notifications. Another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24939573/how-is-mvvmcross-initialized-in-a-notification-service-when-app-is-closed-and-no