# Android app stops when open from push on blank screen with empty toolbar

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

When I receive push notification and click on it my app opens and stops on blank white screen with only empty toolbar.

[image]

It happens not always and only when app long time in background and not killed by system.
Clicking on running apps and selecting my app helps continue loading only

When app killed and opens from cold it works correct. When app recently collapsed it also works correct and opens from push

Thanks

`Activity attributes:`

```
[MvxActivityPresentation]
    [Activity(
        AlwaysRetainTaskState = true,
        Label = "MyPushApp",
        LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop,
        Theme = "@style/Theme.MyTheme",
        ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.User)]
    public class MainActivity : ExtendedDrawerActivity<MenuVM>, ITabletActivity
```

`Activity OnResume():`

```
protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();

            if (ViewModel.InitializeTask.IsSuccessfullyCompleted && CheckIntentForPushNotification())
            {
                ViewModel.PushReceived = false;
                OpenPushNotification();
            }
```

`CheckIntentForPushNotification():`

```
protected bool CheckIntentForPushNotification()
        {
            return Intent != null && Intent.Extras != null && (Intent.HasExtra(MyFirebaseMessagingService.NotificationBodyTag) || Intent.HasExtra(CheckNotificationsService.LocalNotificationTag));
        }
```

`OpenPushNotification():`

```
private void OpenPushNotification()
        {
            if (ViewModel.PushReceived || Intent == null)
            {
                _log.Info("ViewModel.PushReceived || Intent == null");
                return;
            }

            if (Intent.HasExtra(MyFirebaseMessagingService.NotificationBodyTag))
            {
                string notificationText = Intent.GetStringExtra(MyFirebaseMessagingService.NotificationBodyTag);

                string objIds = Intent.GetStringExtra(MyFirebaseMessagingService.ObjectIdTag);
                string objType = Intent.GetStringExtra(MyFirebaseMessagingService.ObjectTypeTag);
                string objSubtype = Intent.GetStringExtra(MyFirebaseMessagingService.ObjectSubtypeTag);
                string moduleType = Intent.GetStringExtra(MyFirebaseMessagingService.ModuleTypeTag);
                string notificationType = Intent.GetStringExtra(MyFirebaseMessagingService.NotificationTypeTag);
                string folderId = Intent.GetStringExtra(MyFirebaseMessagingService.FolderIdTag);

                List<int> ids = objIds?.Split(',')?.Select(id => int.Parse(id))?.ToList();

                Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMvxMessenger>().Publish(new MainPushMessage(this)
                {
                    Text = notificationText,
                    AppLaunchedByNotification = _startWithNotification,
                    NotificationTypeId = string.IsNullOrEmpty(notificationType) ? 0 : Int32.Parse(notificationType),
                    FolderId = string.IsNullOrEmpty(folderId) ? 0 : Int32.Parse(folderId),
                    ObjectIds = ids ?? new List<int>(),
                    ObjectType = objType,
                    ObjectSubtype = objSubtype,
                });
            }

            if (Intent.HasExtra(CheckNotificationsService.LocalNotificationTag))
            {
                Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IMvxMessenger>().Publish(new MainPushMessage(this)
                {
                    IsLocalNotification = true
                });
            }

            Intent = null;
        }
```

`Activity OnNewIntent():`

```
protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
        {
            base.OnNewIntent(intent);

            Intent = intent;
        }
```

Comment: See the answers here, if you need further info let me know: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63791557/mvvmcross-how-to-start-the-application-from-a-notification

Comment: @c.lamont.dev Thanks for your hint and help! Where the most suitable place for your answer? Is that place is OnRestart()?

Comment: From the OnCreate() method I check if the notification intent is there. If so then I do the check to ensure the `MvxAndroidSetupSingleton` is initialised and then I navigate to my `InitialViewModel` directly. I also cache the notification locally, so when my `InitialViewModel` `ViewAppeared` is called, it checks if the notification is cached and then navigates to the appropriate page.