# Initialize mmvcross IOC for Windows Runtime Component Background Task

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, mvvmcross

In building my current (first) Windows Phone app it requires me to create a Windows Runtime Component to achieve the functionality I require.  In order for this setup to work and not duplicate a lot of code from my PCLs into the task class itself, I wanted to use the MMVMCross IOC that I am already using throughout the application.

Unfortunately, the Background Task (IBackgroundTask) is executed in an entirely different process.  Trying to utilize the IOC via Mvx.Resolve throws a NullReferenceException.  I cannot figure out how to initialize the IOC as the standard "setup.cs" method does not work in the Runtime Component.

I do not need the entire MVVMCross stack for this -- just the IOC.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe try the answers and linked answers in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22544832/mvvmcross-how-do-i-access-sqlite-in-a-windows-store-background-task

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.  I have to re-register on the background task, but to initialize you would call the basic initialize method on the simple IOC container:

```
Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.Initialize();
```

Plugins were a problem, as the standard plugin mechanism is not available, but you can manually register the interfaces such as this:

```
Mvx.LazyConstructAndRegisterSingleton<IMvxFileStore>(() => new MvxWindowsCommonBlockingFileStore());
```

Of course, you can still register your other types and interfaces as you normally would.